# Django Framework: Reading Data from MSSQL-Database directly? Or import the dataset to sqlite3?

Tags: django

I would like to build an admin dashboard in Django framework.
So far I have only worked with sqlite3 databases in Django.
However, the admin dashboard should read statistics from an MSSQL database and display them accordingly. (Sales figures as a graph, other sales in a table, etc.)

The turnover figures are very extensive. There are several thousand entries per month and the client would like to be able to filter by any date period.
Only data from the MSSQL database should be read. Writing or updating the data is not desired.

So far this is no problem, but I wonder what is the better solution to implement the project.

Should I connect the MSSQL database directly to Django or should I read the MSSQL database in certain intervals and cache the "results" in a sqlite3 database?

Caching seems to me to be the nicer solution, as we don't need real-time data and the performance of the MSSQL server might not suffer as a result.  But I would have to build an additional connector to transfer the data from MSSQL to sqlite3.

How would you approach such a project?

**Short version: I´d like to display data in django-framework App, should I read directly from MSSQL-Server or should I import the MSSQL-Dataset to local sqlite3-database?**

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [official SQLite page](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html#:%7E:text=SQLite%20is%20often%20used%20as,keeping%20programs%2C%20and%20so%20forth.):

> Situations Where SQLite Works Well:
>
> ***Application file format***
>
> SQLite is often used as the on-disk file format for desktop
> applications such as version control systems, **financial analysis
> tools**, media cataloging and editing suites, CAD packages, record
> keeping programs, and so forth.
>
> ***Cache for enterprise data***
>
> Many applications use SQLite as a cache of relevant content from an
> enterprise RDBMS. This reduces latency, since most queries now occur
> against the local cache and avoid a network round-trip. It also
> reduces the load on the network and on the central database server.
> And in many cases, it means that the client-side application can
> continue operating during network outages.